# How do I submit a form via Ajax in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, .net, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a View made up of several partial views, one of which displays user information with an `Edit` button.

When the `Edit` button is clicked, I make an ajax call to another `Action` that returns a `Partial View` which is loaded into a JQuery-UI modal dialog.

How do I submit this edit form via Ajax and update the `UserInfo` partial view on the main page?

Comment: look here http://mrgsp.md:8080/awesome/foobar (click create or edit)

Comment: Thats pretty much what I need to do..but that looks like its just a demo...not a tutorial or anything...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Ajax Call

```
$('#submitIt').submit(function() {
    var createdBy = $('#createdBy').val();
    $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: '/MyController/GetContact/',
         dataType: "html",
         data: { 'createdBy': createdBy },
         success: function (result) {
            $('#myLittleForm').html(result);
         },
         error: function (request, status, error) {
              //Do Something on Failure
         }
     });
});
```

### Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GetContact(string createdBy)
    {
         ViewData["CreatedBy"] = createdBy;
         return PartialView("MyView");
    }
```

### Markup

```
<div id="myLittleForm">
   <form action="/MyController/GetContact/" method="post">
      <input id="createdBy" type="text"/> <br/>
      <input id="submitIt" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
   </form>
</div>
```

### Note

When you submit the form under markup, the ajax call is made and the div "myLittleForm" is replaced with your partial view.

Comment: Making the ajax call is not my problem... basically I need to know how the controllers will handle the ajax post then update the partial view on the main page(without having to reload the entire main page)...

Comment: Ok I think i got it now. I will give this a try.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: oops, the scripts didn't show - fixing
You'll need to reference the Ajax scripts shown here:

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/AjaxLoadedContentScriptFix.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

I don't recall what that last script is, but I'm using it in my app so it probably can't hurt :)

Then you'll need to use Ajax.BeginForm in your view to post a form asynchronously. It takes an AjaxOptions parameter that will allow you to specify the update target, success callbacks, etc. Example:

```
<% Ajax.BeginForm("FormName" , new { id = Model.SomeProperty }, 
       new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "MyDivToUpdate", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" }); %>
```